# Pandora ajax not working with waitForKeyElements

Tags: javascript, ajax, greasemonkey, pandora

Pandora AJAX is not working with waitForKeyElements.  I have spent a few hours trying to see where I went wrong and can't work it out.

It works once but doesn't work when the next track is played.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Pandora I am listening to
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Pandora I am listening to
// @author       You
// @match        http*://www.pandora.com/*
// @include      https://www.pandora.com/station/play/*
// @require      https://gist.githubusercontent.com/BrockA/2625891/raw/9c97aa67ff9c5d56be34a55ad6c18a314e5eb548/waitForKeyElements.js
// @require     http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==

function liveNow() {
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log(`Now Playing ${$(".songTitle")[0].innerHTML}`);
    }, 6000);  // delay for loading of music

}

waitForKeyElements ("#trackInfoContainer .songTitle", liveNow);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`#trackInfoContainer` is being reused (not created afresh) for each additional track.

So, it's not enough to wait for the node's *creation*, you must also check that the *contents* have changed.
Here's how to do that with waitForKeyElements:

```
waitForKeyElements ("#trackInfoContainer .songTitle", liveNow);

function liveNow (jNode) {
    var titleText  = jNode.text ().trim ();
    var lastText   = jNode.data ("lastText")  ||  "";

    if (titleText != lastText) {
        jNode.data ("lastText", titleText);
        console.log (`Now Playing ${titleText}`);
    }
    return true;  //-- Tell waitForKeyElements to keep checking this node.
}
```

Comment: Thanks Brock, you are awesome.